# Simplest code that can host html files in node.js through Cloud Functions hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So, after reading a lot of documentation and tutorials, I realized that `node.js` can use `"var http = require('http')"` and `"var fs = require('fs')"` and some other code lines to serve html files but if it is hosted by `Firebase Cloud Functions`, that would not work because Firebase Cloud Functions works differently.

Can I get any simple code example how I can serve an html file index.html within node.js for Firebase Cloud Functions hosting?

Comment: Any updates to this? Have you found a way to serve an HTML file using Firebase Cloud Function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply host your index.html file by putting it in /public folder and deploy to Firebase Host. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Steps are quick simple.
1. Install FirebaseCLI
2. Call `$firebase init` - to create the project and generate `firebase.json`, `package.json`, a `public` folder with .html files
3. modify the file and upload using the command `$firebase deploy`

This works for static (just HTML) or SPA (single page application)

Cloud Function is mostly used to build dynamic websites and API.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I specifically asked for hosting dynamic web via node.js onto Firebase Cloud Functions. What you're talking about is hosting static content WHICH does not go through Cloud Functions. I am not trying to host static content.